# Как обрабатывать объект поставив значения по возрастанию?

Tags: php

есть такой xml

```
<category id="68" parentId="6">Шубы</category>
<category id="52" parentId="6">Юбки</category>
<category id="1">Главная</category>
<category id="8">Доставка и оплата</category>
<category id="6">Женская одежда</category>
<category id="9">Контакты</category>
```

это не весь документ а часть  для примера, значения из него я получаю в виде объекта

```
 object(SimpleXMLElement)[109]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '46' (length=2)
      'parentId' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 0 => string '3D' (length=2)
```

category где в `category[id]` хранится значение id в `category[parentId]` хранится значение `parentId` вопрос как мне обрабатывать объект по возрастающей значения `category[id]`
И ещё как мне получить вот это значение  `public 0 => string '3D' (length=2)`